# How to solve $x^3-2x^2-3x=0$

Tags: polynomials

Is there a way I can write this differently so that I can use the quadratic formula, or do I have to solve this in a different way, without using the formula?

Answer (score 3):

Factor out the $x$, getting $x(x^2-2x-3)=0$  Now one of the factors must be zero.  You can use the quadratic formula on the second, or maybe you can factor it by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$x^3-2x^2-3x = x(x^2-2x-3)=x(x-3)(x+1), $$
and hence the roots are $x=0$, $x=3$, and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3-2x^2-3x=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x(x-3)(x+1)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x-3=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=0\space\space\vee\space\space x=3\space\space\vee\space\space x=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

By inspection factor out $x$.

$ 1\, x^2 - 2 x - 3 = 0 $

$ 1+ (-3) = -2 $

so $(x+1) $ is a factor. Factor this also out, assuming this rule is known. Else find factor by inspection/trial & error/quadratic formula methods..

You are now left with $(x-3)$

Roots are $ x= 0, -1,3.